# Best current rails background task method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to find out the best way to run scripts in the background. I have been looking around and found plenty of options, but many/most seem to have become inactive in the past few years. Let me describe my needs.

The rails app is basically a front-end to configure when and how these scripts will be run. The scripts run and generate reports and send email alerts. So the user must be able to configure the start times and how often these scripts will run dynamically. The scripts themselves should have access to the rails environment in order to save the resulting reports in the DB.

Just trying to figure out the best method from the myriad of options.

Comment: how about active jobs? I just read about it but looks promising.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're looking for a background job queuing system.

For that, you're either looking for [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) or [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). Both support scheduling tasks at some point in the future -- delayed_job does this natively, whereas resque has a plugin for it called [resque_scheduler](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler).

You would enqueue jobs in the background with parameters that you specify, and then at the time you selected they'll be executed. You can set jobs to recur indefinitely or a fixed number of times (at least with resque-scheduler, not sure about delayed_job).

delayed_job is easier to set up since it saves everything in the database. resque is more robust but requires you to have redis in your stack -- but if you do already it's pretty much the ideal solution for your problem.

Answer (score 12):

I recently learned about [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), and I think it is really great.

There's also a RailsCast about it - [Sidekiq](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq).

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the gem whenever at https://github.com/javan/whenever.

It allows you to schedule tasks like cron jobs.

Works very well under linux, and the last commit was 14 days ago. A friend of mine used it in a project and was pretty satisfied with it.

edit: take a look at the gem [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) as well, it is good for executing long tasks in the background. Useful when creating a cron job only to start other tasks.

Comment: I saw this, but maybe I am not understanding how to use it exactly, it seems like you statically create your tasks in the schedule.rb file. So could I modify my jobs at run time? Basically, I want this, but want it to be configurable from my rails app by the user.

Comment: The simple solution would be to think about the minimum period of the user's scheduled jobs. If executing all pending jobs every hour will be enough for your needs, you could make one cron job to run every hour, or every ten minutes, iterate over the list of pending jobs, executing the ones that should be. It's much simpler than trying to 'metaprogramatically' create a crontab or something like that. If that's not the case, well, good luck :)