# RoR schedule job

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to run some cron schedule task in my app. I have figured out the code, but I'm not sure where to put it. Should I put all code into job file? The code performs such tasks:

1. Retrieve XML data from 3rd party websites.
2. Do some filtering and add data to array.
3. Push data from array to database.

Code is performed every hour.

Comment: Are you asking how to schedule it, or what?

Comment: Perhaps this link will give you some answers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693493/best-current-rails-background-task-method

Comment: @DaveNewton To test code iwrited it all in to controller. But I don't know if it's ok to have this codr in the controller or should I move it to job. This code will be runned in background.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some kind of a parser for XML data retrieval, and store this class into the `lib` directory. Other stuff like filtering and pushing data from database - you can implement this directly in the job. As the job grows, you will see what can be moved elsewhere or extended.